# How to override jetty's javax.mail version?

Tags: maven, jetty, lift, jakarta-mail

In my pom.xml I have this excerpt to override lift's default mailer:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
  <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.liftweb</groupId>
    <artifactId>lift-util_2.9.0-1</artifactId>
    <version>${lift.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <!--Using mail 1.4.4 instead-->
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Works fine, the [dependency tree](https://gist.github.com/2427dde2ab5c3cd86f2b) shows no sign of javax.mail 1.4.1. But I'm still getting javax.mailer of version 1.4.1 in my m2 repository, when I start it with `mvn jetty:run`. I suppose, jetty uses 1.4.1. How do I override it? Complete pom.xml is [here](https://gist.github.com/22f9ad0e65397c2637a0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've found the solution. Needed to add required version of javax mail to the `<dependencyManagement>` section:

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
      <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.4</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```